# How do I insert a new screen when using a collectionView as the container?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create an app which uses a collectionView as its base for paging between screens. For one of the features I would like to insert a screen(collectionView Cell) when the user taps on a button and remove the screen(collectionView Cell) when the user taps the button again. I have tried implementing insert and delete methods shown below however when they are called it seems to just slide the cells down without letting me modify them.When the cells are slid down it creates a glitchy user experience. How can I add a cell modify it and then remove it without interfering with the user experience?

Below is the code where the cells are added and removed:

```
func addCell(sender:Any?){
    self.numberOfItemsInSections += 1
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: IndexPath(item:1,section:0)) as! customCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .purple
    //newCell.label.text = "new cell added"
    self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item:1,section:0)])

}

func removeCell(sender: Any?) {
    self.numberOfItemsInSections -= 1
    self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item:1,section:0)])


}
```

Below is the code in its entirety

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,addRemoveCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var numberOfItemsInSections:Int = 3

    var cellType:[String] = ["customCell"]
    var cellClass:[Any]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(customCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfItemsInSections
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as!  customCell
        cell.addRemoveCellDelegate = self
        cell.label.text = "\(indexPath)"
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func addCell(sender:Any?){
        self.numberOfItemsInSections += 1
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: IndexPath(item:1,section:0)) as! customCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .purple
        //newCell.label.text = "new cell added"
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item:1,section:0)])

    }

    func removeCell(sender: Any?) {
        self.numberOfItemsInSections -= 1
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item:1,section:0)])


    }



}

protocol addRemoveCell{
    func addCell(sender:Any?)
    func removeCell(sender:Any?)
}

class customCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    var button:UIButton!
    var label:UILabel!
    var addRemoveCellDelegate:addRemoveCell?
    var addCell:Bool = true

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
         self.button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midX, width: self.frame.midX, height: self.frame.midX))
        self.addSubview(button)


        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height/8))
        self.addSubview(label)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        label.backgroundColor = .green
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .orange

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -18).isActive = true
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func  buttonTapped(){
    print("The button was tapped")
        if addCell{
        if let delegate = addRemoveCellDelegate{
            print("Inside of addCell")
            delegate.addCell(sender: self)
        }
            addCell = !addCell
        }
        else{
            if let delegate = addRemoveCellDelegate{
              delegate.removeCell(sender: self)
            }
            addCell = !addCell
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `modify them`?

Comment: @0xa6a I would like to change the properties of a custom UICollectionViewCell which serves as the screen. I would like to cast the cell that I insert as a certain custom UICollectionViewCell and then adjust its properties similar to how one would in the `cellForItemAt` function.

Comment: Did try to modify in the `cellForItemAt` method?

Comment: @0xa6a Ive tried this but it assigns the cells based on indexPath static so when I try to add a new screen in, the cellForItemAt loads all of the cells in the same order they were in from the beginning of the app, adding another cell onto the end of the collectionview without modifying the cell that was just inserted.